# How to pull company insights using LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

Is there a way to pull company insights info using one of the LinkedIn API's? I have a premium account and have created an app on the LinkedIn developers platform. I can’t seem to find a way to fetch company data such as number of employees (by category and total), headcount growth (3m, 6m, 1yr, 2yr), job openings by category, etc.

[image]
[image]

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this easily using organizationPageStatistics and brandPageStatistics APIs
just request the following link

GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization={organization URN}

if you need to read more you can read the documentation 
[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/page-statistics)

Comment: Thank you for the info Tariq. From your experience, would I be able to retrieve info on companies that i'm not following nor a member of? Looking at the documentation it looks like these companies have to add me as "administrator" or somehow approve me to have access to such statistics. But yet using the LinkeIn website that data is readily available to me on any company i'm browsing. This is what i'm referring to (the paragraph in blue): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-lookup-api

Comment: as it mentioned in the documentations APIs that do not require administrative access will only return the following fields: id, name, localizedName, vanityName, logoV2, and location so i don't think you will be able to pull stats of other Organizations. what are the data you are looking for, please give an example ? if you are only interested in the number of followers, then u can retrieve it using the following link https://api.linkedin.com/v2/networkSizes/urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%XXXXXXXX?edgeType=CompanyFollowedByMember